# R Shiny - extendShinyjs Error parsing the JavaScript code provided

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I am testing **extendShinyJs** with the simple test on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs).

I have installed the V8 package, but I get this error, even with the sample script: 
**Error : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript code provided.**

I also tried moving the JavaScript code into a separate file under www folder.

Additional info of the current session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Any idea of how to run extendShinyjs?

In **ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyAce)
#library(V8)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),


     extendShinyjs(text = "myfunc.js"),

       navbarPage("Tweets stuff",
tabPanel("Contact",
       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           textInput("ctFrom", "From:", value=""),
           textInput("ctSubject", "Subject:", value="Sugerencias BTT"),
           actionButton("ctSend", "Send")
         ),
         mainPanel(
           aceEditor("ctMessage", value="")
         )
       )
    ))
)
```

)

```
myfunc.js (in www folder):

    shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){
      $('body').css('background', params);
    };
```

**server.R:**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #Programming with Twitter API

  observeEvent(input$ctSend, {
    #I have more things here
    js$pageCol (input$ctSend)
  })
}
```

Please, ask me if you think you need to see more code. **I wanted to clear the text inside the "aceEditor".**

Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: as a sanity check can you show us the code? i just installed shiny and v8 and ran the example but could not reproduce the error until i intentionally added a typo into the JS portion

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of `shinyjs`, that error only happens if your javascript is literally not valid. If you could post a fully reproducible sample code that gets an error, I could try to help debug

Comment: I haven't tried running your code yet, but since you're using a separate js file, you need to do `extendShinyjs(script = "myfunc.js")`. You use the `text` argument only if you provide the JS code as a string. PS. It'd be easier to debug if you post a minimal example, not one that includes shinyAce and other UI components too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can run your example (but for simplicity I made the JS code a string instead of its own file. If you want it to be in a file, you need to use the `file =` parameter as I said in my comment.

Just to prove that the JS works, I changed the JS function from "changing the background" to simply printing the value of the button.  Let me know if this exact code is producing an error:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyAce)

jscode <- "    shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){
      alert(params);
    };"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),


    extendShinyjs(text = jscode),

    navbarPage("Tweets stuff",
               tabPanel("Contact",
                        sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(
                            textInput("ctFrom", "From:", value=""),
                            textInput("ctSubject", "Subject:", value="Sugerencias BTT"),
                            actionButton("ctSend", "Send")
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            aceEditor("ctMessage", value="")
                          )
                        )
               ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$ctSend, {
      #I have more things here
      js$pageCol (input$ctSend)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help. Of course it works! In case of using the script file, I have tested with extendShinyjs(script = "www\\myfuncs.js"), as commented before and it works!